# Unable to create OpenGL window in SDL2

Tags: opengl, c++, sdl2

I am currently working on a C++ + SDL2 game engine and I am stuck on a problem. The problem is that whenever I pass `SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL` to `SDL_CreateWindow()`, it return null and so my program stops. But it works fine if I pass any other flag while not passing `SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL`.
This is the function I am calling `SDL_CreateWindow()`:

```
Game::Game(const char* title, int w, int h, int x, int y, int glmajversion, int glminversion, Uint32 flags){
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0){
        std::cout<<"[Error]: Unable to initialize SDL2."<<std::endl;
    }

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, glminversion);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, glmajversion);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 32);
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, x, y, w, h, flags);
    if (!window){
        std::cout<<"[Error]: Unable to create SDL2 window."<<std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window, context);
}
```

If I call `SDL_GetError()` before exiting, it returns "Couldn't find matching GLX visual".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake. I set the depth buffer to 32 bit which my computer doesn't have a visual for. Changing depth buffer to 24 bit fixed the error.